# Service not repeating

Tags: android, android-service

MyBroadCast

```
public class BackupBroadCast extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, BackupService.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
```

MyService

```
public class BackupService extends Service {

    public int REQUEST_CODE = 99999;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("Service", "onCreate");
        ativarTemporizador();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //HERE COME THE CODE TO EXECUTE EVERY x time the alarm call the service
        Log.d("Service", "onStartCommand");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    public void ativarTemporizador() {
        Log.d("Service", "Start Timer");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackupBroadCast.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() /*Start Right NOW*/,
                    (10000 /*Repeat Every 10seconds*/), pIntent);
    }
}
```

how i start the Service on App start:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BackupService.class);
            startService(i);
```

but for unknow reason the Alarm is not executing the service each 10 seconds (like i configured)

it has a random time

```
04-22 23:13:47.118 -> onCreate
04-22 23:13:47.118 -> Start Timer
04-22 23:13:47.118 -> onStartCommand
04-22 23:14:10.758 -> onStartCommand
04-22 23:15:10.868 -> onStartCommand
04-22 23:16:11.288 -> onStartCommand
04-22 23:16:48.998 -> onStartCommand
04-22 23:18:11.498 -> onStartCommand
```

how can i make it run the onCommand every x time (i will give user option to do backup in a predefined time)

Comment: Please consult the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). As of KitKat, if your `targetSdkVersion`>=19, `setRepeating()` is inexact. You need to use `setExact()`, and set the alarm again for the desired interval each time it fires.

Answer (score 0):

since i need to use Api 16 >=, i changed

now i calll the starTimer inside the onStartCommand, so when it run for the first time start the timer, when timer get triggered, restart and go on, now its 100% on correctly time

thank you

```
   public void startTimer() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackupBroadCast.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pIntent);
    }
```